# iOS 9 Beta 2 Network Issues with MeteorJS

Tags: ios, meteor, beta

I´ve installed the new **iOS 9 Beta and Xcode 7** to test meteor apps with the coming iOS Version. I figured out that there are some network related issues.

The Client (iPhone) can´t connect to the server to subscribe into the published collections. If I cast an eye on the logs it looks like its serving the files in the "public" folder. After serving the public folder it drops a console log "**network**". Its not really an error message its just say "**network**". My app was running on iOS 8 without issues.

I´ve also tested it with the leaderboard example. The leaderboard app is running but there are no collections served to display the player names.

anyone with the same issues? or ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your app in Xcode. You can access it at .meteor/local/cordova-build

Find your app's info.plist in the Xcode browser.

1) Create a new key, `NSAppTransportSecurity`

2) The value should be a dictionary containing another key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` that is set to true.

This should solve the issue. iOS 9 does not allow you to connect to sites without SSL. This makes it hard to develop without reverting the security setting with the policy above.

More info: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4560